# Create a large matrix as a typedef in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, matrix, multidimensional-array, out-of-memory

I am trying to create a 600*600 Matrix as user-defined type and later use this type for other Matrices. The Problem is it's throwing an error stating that the variable size of "content" cannot be more than 64kb.

My code is as follows:

```
Type Matrixtype
  Contents(1to600,1 to600) As double
End Type
```

Comment: Did you try to define it as a class?

Comment: no it is in VBA so i dint use class..i am able to create matrix of size 150*150.it doesnt allow more than that

Comment: Do you really expect to populate more than a fraction of the cells in such a huge structure? If not, you might consider implementing a *sparse matrix*. Might think of a class representing an entry with a virtual column and row number,  with methods to "iterate" over rows or columns.

Answer (score 2):

From here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278742.aspx

> The size of a user-defined type exceeds 64K.
>
> Reduce the size of the user-defined type. Generally the size of a user-defined type equals the sum of the sizes specified for its elements. On some platforms there may be padding between the elements to keep them aligned on word boundaries. If you nest one user-defined type in another, the size of the nested type must be included in the size of the new type.

Doubles are 8 bytes. 360,000 doubles is 2.9 million bytes (~2,800 kb). That's why you can't have a data structure of Doubles that's 600 square. You also can't have 150 square unless you change the data type to something smaller than a Double.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this, so the best advice I can give you is to create a class and maintain the array in there.  Create a class and name the module CTest. In it, put this code

```
Private mdContents(1 To 600, 1 To 600) As Double

Public Property Let Contents(ByVal lOne As Long, ByVal lTwo As Long, ByVal dValue As Double)
    mdContents(lOne, lTwo) = dValue
End Property

Public Property Get Contents(ByVal lOne As Long, ByVal lTwo As Long) As Double
    Contents = mdContents(lOne, lTwo)
End Property
```

Now, in a standard module, you can create however many copies of this class that you need.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim clsOne As CTest
    Dim clsTwo As CTest

    Set clsOne = New CTest
    clsOne.Contents(1, 1) = 2 ^ 2

    Set clsTwo = New CTest
    clsTwo.Contents(10, 10) = 2 ^ 3

    Debug.Print clsOne.Contents(1, 1), clsTwo.Contents(10, 10)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thnak you so much for the help i hope the issue is resolved.it was a very good idea